# Unique solution: $f(x)$ not globally lipschitz

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I don't understand the part of the question underlined in green. 
[image]

I would normally answer this by showing that $f(x)=1+x^2$ is globally lipschitz but it is not.

Comment: It's been a long time since I've thought about this, but isn't uniqueness a question of *local* Lipschitzness? The standard problem child is $f(x)=\sqrt{|x|}$.

Comment: OP: To avoid the discussion to make circles (it already does), you might want to cite the theorem that was given to you for uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

Local Lipschitz is enough to guarantee uniqueness. Since this function is continuously differentiable on all of the real line, it is locally Lipschitz.

This follows from the mean value theorem: $f(x) - f(y) = f'(\xi)(x-y)$ then we take the maximum, $M$, of $f'(\xi)$ over a closed interval $[a,b]$ to find:

$$|f(x) - f(y)| \le M |x-y|$$ for all $x,y \in [a,b]$.

Comment: I understand the MVT but I do not follow your argument leading to the locally Lipschitz inequality. Does [a,b] cover the original [x,y] of the MVT?

Comment: Yes $[a,b]$ is assumed to contain $[x,y]$ in this case.

Comment: I am confused as to why Locally lipschitz guarantees uniqueness. In [https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Picard%27s_Existence_Theorem], do we not require that $f$ is bounded (as well as being continuous)? How would I go about showing that $f$ is bounded here. Would I have to show it were bounded $\forall x$?

Comment: Local Lipschitz guarantees uniqueness because a solution can be generated via iteration and the Banach fixed point theorem. The Banach fixed point theorem guarantees the existence and uniqueness of a fixed point for what are called contractive operators.

Comment: The solution is guaranteed in a neighborhood of a starting point. Here we declare that $f$ is bounded in a small closed neighborhood of the origin, because it is continuous (from the local Lipschitz property).

Comment: The solution is guaranteed on an open set, so do we just take the closure of this set to get the small closed neighbourhood on which $f$ is bounded?

Comment: Yes, either the closure, or a closed subset of your open set.

Comment: A closed subset of the open set on which $f$ is defined, rather than the open set where $x(t)$ is  unique?

Answer (score 0):

To find general solution, integrate ODE 
$$
\frac{dx}{1+x^2}=dt,
$$
which yields
$$
\arctan{x}=t+C.
$$
Initial condition $x(0)=x_0$ implies $C=\arctan{x_0}$. Thus you get
$$
\arctan{x}=t+\arctan{x_0}.
$$
Solution $x=x(t)$ is unique since *arctan* is one-to-one. Given any $x_0\in \mathbb{R}$, the blowup moment will be $t_0=\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan{x_0}$. Of course, function $f(x)=1+x^2$ is locally Lipschitz, which guarantees uniqueness, but not globally Lipschitz making it possible for a solution to blow up in finite time.